# Multiplying float values "possible lossy conversion from double to float"

Tags: java, floating-point-conversion

I have this problem wherein I have to convert kilometers into miles. I'm a novice programmer so bear with me.

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class problem1 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        float m;
        float km;

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a distance in kilometers:");
        km=input.nextFloat();
        m=km*0.621371;
        System.out.println("This is equal to: "+m);
    }
}
```

It gives me an error saying:

```
Incompatible types:possible lossy conversion from double to float.
```

Comment: HINT: Floating point numbers are by default of `double` type.

Comment: if you want to use float use f at the end like 0.621371f

Comment: I'm guessing you mean lossy conversion? Have you tried googling the error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645783/possible-lossy-conversion-from-double-to-float-given-float-values

Comment: In addition to what you'll learn from the answers, also learn that formatting and coding conventions are very important for communication with your fellow programmers (including those reading your code in the future). Class names should begin with a capital letter, and the code blocks should be properly indented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to set a `double` to a `float` variable

To fix, change this line

```
m=km*0.621371;
```

to

```
m=km*0.621371f;
```

Comment: It is consider a bad programming practice to use magic numbers. By only looking at this code you can not tell what does 0.621371 mean?

Answer (score 1):

The value `0.621371` is a `double` literal, so the `km` values is promoted to `double` when multiplied.  Storing the `double` product back to `m` would be a conversion that could lose data (`double` to `float`).

To keep the data as a `float`, use a `float` literal, with a `f` on the end:

```
m=km*0.621371f;
```

Normally a `double` for the results would be just fine, so you could also just change the datatypes of `m` and `km` to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define constant variable as a float, since km is read as a float.

```
final float KM_TO_ML = 0.621371F;
m = km * KM_TO_ML;
```